# How to parse specific characters of a string to integer?

Tags: c#, winforms, string, parsing, integer

```
string abc = "07:00 - 19:00"
x  = int.Parse(only first two characters) // should be 7
y  = int.Parse(only 9th and 10th characters) // should be 19
```

How could I say this, please ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use Substring method of string class to extract the required set of characters.

```
string abc = "07:00 - 19:00";
x  = int.Parse(abc.Substring(0,2)); // should be 7
y  = int.Parse(abc.Substring(8,2)); // should be 19
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no `int.Parse` that takes a range, so either:

- write your own parser (yeuch)
- use `Substring` first, and then use `int.Parse` on the substring

so:

```
x = int.Parse(abc.Substring(0,2));
```

etc